# detecting countours of this image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, medical

I want to detect white blood cells (WBCs) and count them, so i had to make some steps and reached this image and don't know what to do next.

Original image:

[image: Original image]

gray then closing morphology then thresholding:

[image: gray then closing morphology then thresholding]

my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("images/image.jpg")
output = im.copy()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurG = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, (9, 9), 0)
blurM = cv2.medianBlur(gray_image, 5)
cv2.imwrite("gray.jpg",gray_image)


res,thresh_img=cv2.threshold(blurM,135,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8) 
closing= cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_img,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel,iterations=2)
cv2.imwrite("result3.jpg",closing)
```

Comment: Not everyone has biology knowledge here. What are _wbcs_? Do you want to segment the purple blobs?

Answer (score 2):

If the point is on a contour, it has neighbors with different values, and the gaussian blur with neigbors will be different.

So you just check for differences between "closing" image and his gaussian blur.

```
blurNeighbor = cv2.GaussianBlur(closing, (3, 3), 0)

#contour is any "closing" pixel different from "blurNeighbor"
contour=(blurNeighbor!=closing).astype(np.uint8)*255
cv2.imshow("Contour", contour)
cv2.waitKey(10)
```

[image: contour]

You can estimate the number of blobs by dividing the number of black pixels in "closing" by the median blob size.

For this image, it gives 33.5 blobs:

```
#detect blobs in "closing"
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByArea = False
params.filterByInertia = False
params.filterByConvexity = False

detector=cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
blobs=detector.detect(closing)

#draw detected blobs
img_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(closing, blobs, outImage=np.array([]), color=(0, 0, 255),flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv2.imshow("Detected blobs", img_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(10)

#estimate the number of blobs
blobAreas=np.sort([np.pi/4*b.size**2 for b in blobs])
medianArea=np.median(blobAreas)
blobCountEstimation=np.sum(closing==0)/medianArea

print(f"Estimated number of blobs: {blobCountEstimation:.1f}")
>>>Estimated number of blobs: 33.5
```

[image: detected blobs]